# Async resolution order for await single promise vs async iterators

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

So this is based on a discovery I made while working on a package to simplify async generators or iterators.

Normally the execution order of promises is determined by the time it was called, meaning the following is true (in Chrome & Node on Windows & Mac).

```js
let resolve, promise = new Promise(r => resolve = r);

(async () => {
  await promise
  console.log('1st')
})();
(async () => {
  await promise
  console.log('2nd')
})();

resolve();
```

However, this order is not respected when dealing with async generators or iterators

```js
let resolve, promise = new Promise(r => resolve = r);

async function* generator() {
   yield promise
}

(async () => { // regular promise
  await promise
  console.log('1st')
})();
(async () => { // promise generator
 for await (let _ of generator())
   console.log('3rd (should be 2nd)')
})();
(async () => { // promise iterator
 for await (let _ of [promise])
   console.log('4th (should be 3rd)')
})();
(async () => { // regular promise again
  await promise
  console.log('2nd (should be 4th)')
})();

resolve();
```

I'm unsure if "execution /resolution order" is the correct term for this, but is this order guaranteed? Is there anything that can be done to make this order guaranteed within a Node or Browser program?

Comment: Are you sure they're generators? They don't look like a generator to me? Aren't these async iterators?

Comment: I would rather view the "fixed order" of the first example to be an implementation detail. I am not 100% sure, but I don't think the spec guarantees anything of the sort.

Comment: @InchHigh You are right, updated question to reflect changes.

Comment: @Amadan That is what I suspect, but have been unable to find any source for this (Mainly because I am unsure what it is actually called) and also unable to produce a different result.

Comment: I think the difference here is promise flattening: `Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(1))` will also take two microtasks to call `.then` handlers.

Comment: @Amadan The [spec](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-37) does mention that the execution order should be preserved.

Comment: That would make sense, @JonasWilms but I don't see how `for await (let _ of [promise])` is wrapping a promise with another promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promise resolution order is guaranteed:

> **25.6.1.8 TriggerPromiseReactions ( reactions, argument )**
>
> [...]
>
> 1. For each *reaction* in *reactions*, in **original insertion order**, do
>
>    a. Perform EnqueueJob("PromiseJobs", PromiseReactionJob, << reaction, arguments >>)

For understanding what's going on with iterators, have a look at this snippet:

```js
let resolve, promise = new Promise(r => resolve = r);

let chained = promise.then(it => Promise.resolve());

(async () => {
  await chained;
  console.log("2nd");
})();

(async () => { // regular promise
  await promise
  console.log('1st')
})();


resolve();
```

As you can see, a Promise that gets resolved when another Promise resolved will take two microticks.

And that's what happens in an async iterator. When you call `.next`, a Promise gets returned and stored in the iterators internal queue. At the same time, the execution of the async generator function continues. Then when the async iterator `yields` (after one microtick in your case), it resolves the next promise in the queue. As promise resolution is another microtasks, that'll take two ticks in total.

```
resolve();
// 1 microtick
await promise; // generators await yielded promises implicitly
yield; 
// 1 microtick
for await(const _ of iterator)
```

Comment: Great, that mirrors [this spec](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-37) and is what I expected. However, if that is the case then why isn't the 2nd example respecting the insertion order?

Comment: @MoPro yes, it's more complicated than i thought when starting to write down an answer ...

Comment: @MoPro it is. There are just two promises involved here.

Comment: Interesting, I thought that the only thing that would take microticks are asynchronous functions. Having generators and yielding take a microticks makes sense but having a simple iterator seems counter intuitive. Thanks for the info tho!